# btn.eventListener is not a function!

Tags: javascript, html, dom, function

Cuando deseo agregar un event listener a un objeto del html me aparece en la consola del navegador el error eventlistener is not a function, el codigo es el siguiente. este script se ejcuta en un archivo simple de html.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', adding, false);

function adding(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve en un `array` la cantidad de elementos encontrados, por ende la variable `btn` es un `array` y entonces al intentar hacer  `addEventListener()` te dice que no es una función.
Conclusión, lo que deberías hacer es o bien recorrer todos los elementos del array y agregale los eventos o decirle que sólo al primero le cree el evento (eso si sólo si vas a saber que es sólo uno).

#### En tu caso

Simplemente agregando el índice del primer array:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

btn[0].addEventListener('click', adding, false);

function adding(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
}
```

#### Haciendo un `for`

La mejor forma para estos casos es crear un `for` para todos los elementos encontrados:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', adding, false);
}

function adding(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: hola he intentado en codepen y ha funcionado de ambas formas el error solo lo arroja la consola de mis navegadores aun siendo codigo js puro, hay alguna solucion???

Comment: Qué error te arroja?

Comment: en chrome btn.eventListener is not a function!
y en firefox btn is null , siendo el mismo codigo que ejecuto en codepen

Comment: En qué orden está el script de javascript? En el `<head>` o al final ante de cerrar el `</body>`?

Comment: en el head! como es comun

Comment: Entonces probá envolver todo el script en `(function() { /* pegar aquí el script */ })()`.